# C++ pointers and classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Trying to solve this question for the last 45 minutes, but couldn't figure out the what I'm suppose to do. Here's the question.

```
class C; //forward declaration
class Cpointer {
 public:

};

class C { //do not modify
   int i;
  public:
   C(int _i=0) : i(_i) {}
   Cpointer operator& () { return Cpointer(this); }
   void Do() { std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl; }
 };


 int main() {
   Cpointer p (new C(100));
   p->Do();
 }
```

**Complete class Cpointer so that the code compiles. Make sure there are no memory leaks.**

As I understand CPointer class takes a C class as a parameter for the constructor.
When I try the below code I'm getting a compiler error telling that 
"use of undefined type C" inside the CPointer's Do function.

```
class Cpointer
{
 C* mCptr;
   public:
  Cpointer(C* cptr) : mCptr(cptr){}
  void Do()
  {
    //mCptr->Do();
  }
};
```

Comment: *Complete class Cpointer so that the code compiles*? What kind of useless homework assignment is this?

Comment: Did you remove the forward declaration? It should be before the CPointer class.

Comment: No it's not a homework. it was a question on my previous midterm exam.

Comment: Hint: `Cpointer` doesn't need a `Do` function, and you need to overload an operator.

Comment: Another hint: you will need one more special method to prevent memory leak.

Comment: As written, I don't think it is possible to both guard against memory leaks, and have `return Cpointer(this)` and `Cpointer ptr(new C(100))` in the same program.  Maybe if `C::operator &` were marked const.  I hope you didn't copy this straight from the exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel slightly uneasy posting solution but since you say it's not a homework... Here it is:

```
class Cpointer {
    C* ptr;
    public:
        Cpointer(C* c) : ptr(c) { }
        ~Cpointer() { delete ptr; }
        C* operator->() { return ptr; }
};
```

There are three points here:

1. Constructor to get the `C*` pointer and store it in the improvided pointer-like class.
2. Destructor to remove the object heap-allocated `C` when `p` gets out of scope of `main` function.
3. Overloaded `->` operator so that `p->Do();` will correctly invoke the `C::Do` method.

Basically, what you were asked to implement is a partial functionality of the standard `auto_ptr` class.

Comment: This is amazing thanks a lot. I don't know why I didn't think about overloading the -> operator.

Comment: This has a serious problem when `Cpointer` objects are copied - multiple deletes of `Cpointer::ptr`. Note that even though there is a copy operation in the code from the call to `C::operator&()`, the problem might not be demonstrated because the compiler is permitted to elide the copy (and they generally do).

Comment: Indeed `Cpointer` has such problems if it were to be used as general purpose pointer-like class.  I understand the task was rather academic so a general solution was not reqiured. (That solution could be the `std::auto_ptr` I mentioned).

Answer (score 2):

Given the way Cpointer is used in main(), it has to be implemented like this:

```
class Cpointer
{
private:
    C* c:
public:
    Cpointer(C* _c) : c(_c) {}
    ~Cpointer() { delete c; }
    C* operator ->() { return c; }
};
```

The problem is that Cpointer is also used by C's overriden '&' operator, and this kind of implementation will not work for that usage. Memory corruption will occur, especially if the C instance is declared on the stack (which is when an overriden '&' operator is usually needed). To really make this work correctly, C would have to be modified, either to stop using Cpointer, or to contain a reference count that Cpointer manages. Either way violates the "do not modify" restriction on C.

Comment: When I initially read these answers, I just glanced at your destructor and ignored the rest since your answer was clearly wrong.  Glad I gave it another glance.  +1 for pointing out the inconsistant requirements.

Answer (score 0):

so that it compiles, and doesn't leak? ok.

```
class Cpointer
{
   public:
   Cpointer(C* c)
   {  delete c; }
  void Do()
  {  }
   Cpointer* operator ->()
   { return this; }
};
```

Comment: yes I can do that, but I'm not sure if it's the right answer. And look at the p->Do(); instruction inside the main. This won't let it to compile.

Comment: forgot to overload ->(). It compiles now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class C; //forward declaration
class Cpointer {
 public:
 C* mptr;

 Cpointer(C *cptr){
     mptr = cptr;
 }

 ~Cpointer(){
     delete mptr;
 }

 C* operator->() const {
     return mptr;
 }
};
```